# What is the time complexity of Shapiro-Wilk normality test?

Tags: statistical-significance, hypothesis-testing

I am using [the Shapiro-Wilk normality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test), and I am curious about its time complexity. Here is the formula for $W$:

$W = \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_ix_i})^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i-\overline{x})^2}}$

Let's say the sample size is `n`. The summations in the formula are simply $\Theta(n)$ if each operation takes $O(1)$ time. In the denominator, first, we need to calculate the mean, which takes $\Theta(n)$ and can be used for every subtraction. So each subtraction is $O(1)$. In the numerator, there is $a_i$ for each $x_i$. I am not sure how to interpret calculating $a$. Overall time complexity seems like $\Theta(n)$ but these coefficient calculations confuse me.

Is there anybody who can help to find the time complexity of the Shapiro-Wilk normality test?

By the way, I am using `scipy` for calculations. It uses Fortran [in its source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.4/scipy/stats/statlib/swilk.f), and I don't understand the code, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity of that code is $\Theta(n)$. It uses a fast approximation for $a_i$ that is also $\Theta(n)$. However, the code assumes that the observations are in ascending order, and the required sorting will be $\Theta(n\log n)$

The paper behind  the code are [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2347973) and [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2986146)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're right, [the Python code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.4/scipy/stats/morestats.py#L1609-L1683) sorts before sending it to the Fortran code. So, the complexity is $\Theta(n \log n)$